# Error 'orderBy' when updating to Angular 1.5.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I updated Angular on my project, from 1.4.9 to 1.5.3. And on one of the pages I'm getting this error message:

```
'Error: orderBy:notarray Value is not array-like', 'Expected array but received: 0'
```

**Here is template:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="targeting in vm.TargetingsAudience track by $index  | orderBy:orderByName">
                    <td>
                        {{targeting.Name}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="au_content_descr">
                        <p ng-repeat="val in targeting.Values track by $index  | orderBy:orderByName" class="targeting-value">{{val}}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="au_ico_2">
                        <a class="au_del au_fast_ico" ng-click="vm.removeTargeting(targeting)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
                        <a class="au_edit au_fast_ico" ng-click="vm.editTargeting(targeting)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

**vm.TargetingsAudience - is an Array of Objects:**

```
[{Name: "Гео", TargetingCategory: "Audience", TypeId:"Location", Values: [0: "Россия", 1: "Москва", 2: "Московская область"]}]
```

Answer (score 11):

This might be related to a breaking change in angular 1.5

> Filters (orderBy)
>
> Due to [2a85a634](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/2a85a634f86c84f15b411ce009a3515fca7ba580), passing a non-array-like value (other than undefined
>   or null) through the orderBy filter will throw an error. Previously,
>   the input was returned unchanged, which could lead to hard-to-spot
>   bugs and was not consistent with other filters (e.g. filter). Objects
>   considered array-like include: arrays, array subclasses, strings,
>   NodeLists, jqLite/jQuery collections

Try using [AngularJS toArray Filter](https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter)

**EDIT :**

Because you sad you upgraded the app, I assumed it was working before. But to make it working I think you have to switch track by and order by statements

> Note: track by must always be the last expression:

```
<tr ng-repeat="targeting in vm.TargetingsAudience | orderBy:orderByName track by $index  ">

<p ng-repeat="val in targeting.Values | orderBy:orderByName  track by $index  " class="targeting-value">{{val}}</p>
```

Comment: I ran into the same error.  The problem is indeed the `track by` being before the `| orderBy`.  Moving the `track by` to the end fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Change `orderBy:orderByName` to `orderBy:'Name'`